# Attribute Error for Python regarding an object

Tags: python, class, object, attributeerror

Hey I'm trying to get better at python and decided to go through classes. I run the code and it worked up until it calls the object Employees. It gives me an Attribute error: type object 'Employees' has no attribute 'HourlyAssociate'. Can anyone help me out. I've looked all over for a fix and tried a few things but I hit a wall.

```
class Employees:
   
   def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
        def setName(self, name):
            self.name = name

            def getName(self):
                return self.name

class SalariedEmployee(Employees):


    def __init__(self, name, rate, monthly):
        rate.monthly = monthly
        Employees.__init__(self, name)
    

        def setMonthly(rate, monthly):
            rate.monthly = monthly 

            def getMonthly(rate, monthly):
                return rate.monthly

class HourlyEmployee(Employees):

    def __init__(self, name, rate, hourly, time, hours):
        rate.hourly= hourly
        Employees.__init__(self, name)
    
        def setHourly(rate, hourly):
            rate.hourly = hourly 

            def getHourly(rate):
                return rate.hourly
   
                def setHours(time, hours):
                    time.hours = hours

                    def getHours(time, hours):
                        time.hours = hours

import Employee

#main function
def main():

   associates=AssociateList()

   print('All associates hired for the company: ')
   display_associates(associates)
#function for user input, and storing in the objects created. Then store in the array
def AssociateList():

    #an empty array for employee data
    associate_list = []

    # Input to get the number of employee's date the user will be entering in
    numOfAssociates = int(input('How many workers hired today? '))

    #loop for input for each employee

    for num in range(numOfAssociates):

        #input data
        name = input('Enter the name of the worker: ')
        answer = str(input('Enter if associate is hourly or salary: '))

        if answer == ('hourly'):
            hours = int(input('Enter the amount of hours: '))
            hourly = float(input('Enter the hourly rate: '))
        else:
            monthlyRate = int(input('Enter the monthly rate: '))
        print()

        associates = Employees.HourlyAssociate(name, hours, hourly)
        associates = Employees.SalaryAssociate(name, hours, monthlyRate)
        
        associate_list.append(associate)

        return associate_list

    def display_associate(associate_list):
        for associate in associate_list:
            print('Name:', associate.get_name())
            print('Hourly rate: $', associate.get_Hourlyrate())
            print('Hours worked: ', associate.get_Hours())
            print()

#calls the main function
main()
```

Comment: What do you expect `associates = Employees.HourlyAssociate(name, hours, hourly)` to do?

Comment: @GoodDeeds I wanted to put the input data into an object "HourlyAssociate" and put the object into the variable associate. To then put it into the array "associate_list"

Comment: What is the `HourlyAssociate` type? You have not defined any class by that name.

Comment: Are you using the words "employee" and "associate" interchangeably in your code?  Python doesn't understand English synonyms; you'll have to pick one.